# My Windows Bootable USB is not loading

Tags: grub2, usb, windows

My current OS is Ubuntu. I want to install windows to backup my files from my HDD. I have windows CD. I changed the boot order and tried booting from CD. But it didnt boot up. It directly gets booted to Ubuntu. Then I take out the iso from cd and created a bootable USB. Then I again changed the boot order to USB flash drive. But then also it didnt loaded up. Why it is not recognizing the usb..The problem is not with the USB, because I tried using it on another laptop and it worked. Something is problem with my laptop since I installed ubuntu.

If anyone can help me briefly please whatsapp me on 8592805159(+91)

Please help me out

Comment: Some devices have protection that is device specific, and your question to me is off-topic as it's mostly about booting an off-topic OS and you're asking about boot specifics on hardware (this isn't a hardware support site, but a Ubuntu one).  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I know but I am finding some who can help me..not who can advice someting